# Double Buffer a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, double-buffering

I have been reading a lot about Double Buffering as I am working on a 2D game. I have come across many different strategies for implementation, but am unsure how Double Buffering would fit into the way I have created my game window. For example, one article I came across (http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java:Tutorials:Double_Buffering) suggested having a separate method for drawing; however, I suspect this would be applicable if you were drawing shapes, instead of adding components to the window.

Here is my main GUI code (keylistener methods omitted)

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
private Dimension dim;
private CardLayout layout;
private JPanel panel;
private JLayeredPane gameLayers;
private Menu menu;
private MiniGame miniGame;
private Board board;
private Sprite sprite;
private Game game;
private Map map;
private GameState gs;

private Boolean[] keys;


public MainWindow(Game game, GameState gs, Map map, Sprite sprite){
    //Call superclass.
    super();

    addKeyListener(this);

    //Sore references to critical game components.
    this.game = game;//So we can call methods when an event occurs.
    this.gs = gs;
    this.map = map;//Used to construct the board.
                    //The board needs to know the layout of the map.
    this.sprite = sprite;//Used to add the sprite to one of the layers.

    //Instantiate objects.
    dim = new Dimension(800, 600);
    layout = new CardLayout();
    panel = new JPanel(layout);
    menu = new Menu();
    miniGame = new MiniGame();
    board = new Board(map);
    gameLayers = new JLayeredPane();

    //Remove decoration and place window in center of screen.
    setUndecorated(true);
    Dimension screenDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds((screenDim.width /2)-(dim.width/2),
            (screenDim.height/2)-(dim.height/2),
            dim.width,
            dim.height);

    //Add the board to a layer.
    gameLayers.add(board, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    board.setBounds(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
    board.setBoard();

    //Add the sprite to a layer.
    gameLayers.add(sprite, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
    sprite.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

    //Add components to window.
    panel.add(gameLayers, "gameLayers");
    panel.add(miniGame, "miniGame");
    panel.add(menu, "menu");

    //Add the "cards" to the window.
    add(panel);

    //JFrame housekeeping.
    pack();
    setSize(dim);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

    //Holds state when an event is triggered.
    //Ugly hack to circumvent delay issue.
    keys = new Boolean[4];
    for(int i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        keys[i] = false;
    }
}
}
```

How would you recommend I approach this? Bearing in mind that the Board is a JPanel consisting of a grid of scaled images, and the sprite will be a JComponent displaying a scaled image.

Regards,
Jack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the JPanel's paintComponent() Method and paint the content into a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) image first. Once done, copy the content of the BufferedImage into the graphics context you get from paintComponent().

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    //paint using g2d ...

    Graphics2D g2dComponent = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2dComponent.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, 0, 0);  
}
```

Comment: `JPanel` is double buffered by default.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Just saw it in the documentation. Should work though, as general approach of double buffering in Swing.

Comment: Yes, a `BufferedImage` is good for composing an intermediate, e.g. [compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_compositing).

Comment: JPanel did not double buffer for me.  The BufferedImage worked however.

Answer (score 0):

As the Java Graphics Library is not fast, either well functional, you should inform yourself about the 'Lightweight Java Game Library' ( http://lwjgl.org/ ). It uses OpenGL, a strong Graphics Library, using native code.
Lwjgl is also used for the game Minecraft.
Also, OpenGL is used for different languages, so you could learn multi-functional and high-level programming.