# JAppplet Flicker on Opening html

Tags: java, swing, awt, repaint, japplet

I am opening multiple level html's on a Java Applet, my basic window in JApplet and upon it I am opening a 1st secondary html window, & then again opening 2nd secondary html window that will force the main basics JApplet's repaint to be called, and all the windows get repaint again this will produce a kinda flicker.  This scenario will only produced in JRE 7 environement not in JRE 6.

Any direction you can suggest?

PS: I have played with all the paints method of windows but all will reach to the same point.

Comment: For better help sooner post the code which you have written...

Comment: *"Any direction u can suggest"*  I suggest you spell words like 'you' properly & add a question mark '?' to questions.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, I believe you are seeing the applet actually repaint itself. The way around this is to implement double buffering.

A similar question has been asked before, see:

- [Double Buffer a JFrame - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367756/784386)

Other resources:

- [Java Tutorial on Double Buffering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)
- [Applet Tutorial: Double Buffering](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/doublebuffering.html)